# How do you find a maximum or minimum double from a set?

Tags: java, set, double, max, min

In a basic java program, I've defined two methods of a class that are supposed to return the maximum and minimum numbers from a set of four doubles. The value parameter is taken in from a for loop, and then compared to the standing min or max parameter. However, the outputs are not correct and I cannot seem to find out why; I know I have made a logic error somewhere.

The two methods-

```
//calculate the minimum 
public double calcMin(double value, double min)
{
    if (min < value)
   {
       min = value;
   }
   return value;
}

//calculate the maximum
public double calcMax(double value, double max)
{
    if (max < value)
    {
        max = value;
    }
    return max;
}
```

The for loop-

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fillups.length; i ++)
    {
        distance[i] = fillups[i].calcDistance();
        milesPerGallon[i] = fillups[i].calcMPG(distance[i]);
        cost[i] = fillups[i].calcTotalCost();
        minimum = fillups[i].calcMin(distance[i], minimum);
        maximum = fillups[i].calcMax(distance[i], maximum);
        minMPG = fillups[i].calcMin(milesPerGallon[i], minMPG);
        maxMPG = fillups[i].calcMax(milesPerGallon[i], maxMPG);
        minPrice = fillups[i].calcMin(price[i], minPrice);
        maxPrice = fillups[i].calcMax(price[i], maxPrice);
        fillups[i].printResults(i, day[i], distance[i], cost[i], milesPerGallon[i]);  
    }
```

The calcMax method seems to work, but the calcMin does not. Perhaps there is a way to make them work using the Double.MAX_VALUE and Double.MIN_VALUE constants.

Comment: You seem to have identical expressions for each case, when they should be opposite.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-

Comment: Thanks to all for their input. I was able to fix it and move on with your suggestions and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll repeat your two methods:

```
//calculate the minimum 
public double calcMin(double value, double min)
{
    if (min < value)
   {
       min = value;
   }
   return value;
}

//calculate the maximum
public double calcMax(double value, double max)
{
    if (max < value)
    {
        max = value;
    }
   return max;
}
```

Do you see that you use the same logic for `calcMin` as you do for `calcMax`? Replace the `<` in `calcMin` by `>` and it should work.

You are searching for the smaller value thus, if the given value is **smaller** than the current known minimum, then you replace it.
You may start with `Double.MAX_VALUE` for the best known **minimum** at the beginning (and then you make it better every round). Analogously you may use `Double.MIN_VALUE` in the first round as best known **maximum**.

A smaller, much more compact way is to use `Math.min(double, double)` (and *max*).
Your methods themselves do some useless stuff, there is no need to assign `min = value` inside the method as `min` and `value` get deleted upon leaving the scope of this method. You could simply do this:

```
public double calcMin(double value, double min) {
    if (min < value) {
        return min;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

For finding the smallest value in a `Set` you may use `Collections.min(Set)`. But be aware that this method needs to search the whole set. It may be better using a good sorting algorithm first. Also note that a `Set` has no order per definition, a `List` is sort-able.

Well, I think you get the idea. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not really well versed in Java, but aren't arguments passed by value? If so, then changing `min` will have no side effects (i.e. outside the function). In other words, `calcMin(v, minimum);` will not change `minimum`, so the function has absolutely no effect. The same for `calcMax`, of course.

Comment: That is correct. The variables get deleted upon leaving the scope of the method. I wrote this for the purpose of fixing his method. But I also wrote about this.

Comment: I assume that the main goal of `calcMin` and `calcMax` was to change the minimum and maximum values if that was necessary. Since they don't do that, you can simply assign `value` directly. But `minimum` and `maximum` will never change.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what op intended the code to do, he wrote that `calcMax` works. If that is correct he should move the logic outside of the method and ensure that variables `min` and `max` are known and get holded outside of the `calc`-methods. But as far as I can see he ensures this with `minimum = ...calcMin(..., minimum);`

Comment: No, sorry, I misread. Then why not simply Math.min and Math.max?

Comment: Yes, that is a compact way of reaching the same (my answer already included this option). Well, maybe he wants to implement the method by himself instead of using a magic method from Java :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117033/discussion-between-zabuza-and-rudy-velthuis).